# Access Tensorflow tensor value

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a tensor with the following properties. I want to save the `numpy = 1` but I don't know how to access this value. How do I do this?

```
test_labels[1]

<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>
```

Comment: use `test_labels[1].numpy()` to get the value. Next, you can save in many ways, ie np.save

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tf.print()` to get the values of the tensor.

For Example:

```
a=tf.constant(1) #Output:<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>  

tf.print(a) #Output:1
```